# Problem to convert pinescript v4 code to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to convert this line to v5, its written in v4. The options section has problem. When ı try to compile it says "The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'options". I know it looks easy but ı am new to coding. Thanks in advance!

mav = input(title="Moving Average Type", defval="VAR", options=["SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "TMA", "VAR", "WWMA", "ZLEMA", "TSF"])

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function needs to be changed to `input.string()` for this to work, [inputs have been changed in Pine v5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#split-of-input-into-several-functions).

Also note that [Pine has a converter that can convert v4 scripts to v5 automatically](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter).